# Optimize finding matches in array of strings using array of regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, regex

I have two arrays. One that is populated with values pulled from the database and another that is an user uploaded array of regex patterns to match:

```
db_array = ["ABCDEFG", "HIJKLMN", "OPQRSTU", "VWXYZ", etc...]
matching_array = ["(OPQRST)(3)?(.{1,})?", "(WXY)(1)?(.{1,})?", "(HIJKLMN)(3)?(.{1,})?", etc...]
```

Is there a better way to find any/all the matches in the db_array using the matching_array rather than iterating through the matching array and then the db_array and pulling any matches?

```
matching_array.map{|regex| db_array.select{|a| /#{regex}/.match}}
```

The issue is that both of these arrays can be over 3000+ records and that takes a substantial amount of time. Especially since the matching_array is built up to multiple times using different pattern criteria. Trying to limit the amount of db calls I make as well since I dont want to constantly be hitting the server.

Comment: What do you think `(OPQRST)(3)?(.{1,})?` match?

Comment: If you loop the `db_array` and loop `matching_array` inside of it then you can `break` as soon as one of the regexes are a positive match.

Comment: @Toto Sorry, the above regex wasn't exactly given to match...the above was just a quick representation of what the two arrays looked like. I dont have an issue of regex matching, just the amount of time it takes using the above code of .map and .select

Comment: @MonkeyZeus thanks for the suggestion, however I dont want it to break because one matching_array expression could match with multiple db_array values.

Comment: i'd strongly discourage using user-provided regexps. If you execute them on PCRE engine (e.g. the default Ruby `Regexp` class), you can get ReDOSed https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Regular_expression_Denial_of_Service_-_ReDoS

Comment: You should only break the `matching_array` loop and continue the outer `db_array` loop. My assumption is that ruby supports nested breaks, doesn't it?

Comment: @mrzasa agreed, and we dont, for the brevity of the question I left out the full processes. The user uploads a csv doc that has information in it that we use to use internal rules to construct the regex expressions from.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Thanks, Ill look into the breaking out of the inner loop more

Answer (score -1):

If you can be sure that the regular expressions don't use PCRE extensions (look behind, etc), then you can use a much faster regex library.

Google maintains one called re2 (https://github.com/google/re2).

Ruby bindings are available (https://github.com/stefanor/ruby-re2, among others).

Comment: Thanks! Ill take a look at those libraries.

Comment: Was this helpful? I'm curious.